# Custom Object Lookup Field - Posting from web form

Tags: salesforce

I made a custom object in Salesforce and an associated custom lead field that is a Lookup data type.   I'm using a web-to-lead form and altering it to include this custom field (since Salesforce doesn't give you this Lookup field as an option when building a web-to-lead form).  I picked up the name and values of the options in the the lookup, so it looks like this (I'm pretty sure all the values and names are correct..but this doesn't work when trying to post the data to salesforce (no errors, just that the data doesn't populate the field in Salesforce.  I heard this used to work, but it's not working for me...any ideas?

```
 <select name="CF00NU0000002TPVQ" id="CF00NU0000002TPVQ">
<option value="a00U00000023IRH">Session 1</option>
<option value="a00U00000023IhL">Session 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Web-to-Lead handler will accept lookup fields. You could put a picklist field with the text values for the Sessions on the form and then have a trigger populate the lookup field.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy..in that case, I guess I'll need to use a third party solution, like FormStack..too bad Salesforce makes you go this route.

Comment: You could also create a public site in salesforce and embed that instead of inserting the web-to-lead form. Though rather simple, it would require some Visualforce/Apex development capabilities.